# How to return tuples from function and print them vertically?

Tags: python, html, list, return, tuples

I have a list of tuples, for example

```
q = [(Nick,21),(George,41),(Paul,15)]
```

and I am returning them from a function.

An html form is using this function and with the right parameters is printing/showing what the function has returned.

But instead of:

```
|  Name  | Age  |
|  Nick  |  21  |
| George |  41  |
|  Paul  |  15  |
```

it's printing:

```
|  Name  | Age  |
|  Nick  |  21  | George |  41  |  Paul  |  15  |
```

Also, the function returns the q like this:

```
return [("Name", "Age"), q]
```

How can I print the `q` like the first way?

Comment: `print('\n'.join('| {} | {} |'.format(*e) for e in q))`

Comment: Have you tried *concatenating*? `return [("Name", "Age")] + q`.

Comment: @sshashank124: *An html form is using this function and with the right parameters is printing/showing what the function has returned.*, they already have code to print the table.

Comment: Oh my bad. Misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

Your function wants to have the header and the rows all together in one list. Concatenate your header list with the `q` list:

```
return [("Name", "Age")] + q
```